# Using a getter that calls another class, and returns that class as a formatted string?

Tags: java, class, oop, object, methods

I am trying to learn OOP and I have a program that has 3 classes; Person, personprogram(the main), and Date. The Person program contains the constructor for a new Person including their first name, last name, middle initial, and birth date. The birth Date is of type Date, and inside the Date class I have a constructor that takes in 3 integers for the day, month and year of the person birthdate. I am having some trouble understanding how this all works together, and how I can properly call the birthDate. I am going off a UML diagram that my prof gave us to design the program. The objects for the people are created as such:

```
 people = new Person[5];
 people[0] = new Person("Smith", "John", 'T', new Date(4, 2, 1992));
```

Now I can understand how the getters work for the names and middle initial. I simply call the getter from the Person class and it returns the selected one. What I dont understand is what getter am I calling for the BirthDate. If I call the getter for my birthdate like the others:

```
public Date getBirthDate() {
return BirthDate;
}
```

What exactly is that returning? Does that need to call the Date class at all to get the certain birthdate? Since the birthdate is created with another class, does that create another object outside (or inside) of the People objects?

I want to know because I am trying to format that BirthDate into a string, so when the user asks for a persons information it can be shown in the correct format. So inside the Date class I have

```
public String displayFormattedDate() {
    return String.format("%s/%s/%s", String.valueOf(year), String.valueOf(month), String.valueOf(day));
}
```

So, would I call that from the getter inside the Person class? If so how do I do it? Do I need to initialize a new Date object inside the method in order to call it?

EDIT: My classes code

Person:

```
public class Person {

    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private char middleInit;
    private Date birthDate;

    public Person() {}




     public Person(String lastName, String firstName, char middleInit, Date birthDate) {
        //Person p = new Person("Smith", ... );
        setLastName(lastName);
        setFirstName(firstName);
        setMiddleInit(middleInit);
        setBirthDate(birthDate);

    }


    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }


    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }


    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }


    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }


    public char getMiddleInit() {
        return middleInit;
    }


    public void setMiddleInit(char middleInit) {
        this.middleInit = middleInit;
    }


    public Date getBirthDate() {
        Date birthday = new Date();
        return birthDate.displayFormattedDate;

    }


    public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }


    public String getFullName() {
        return String.format("%s, %s %s.", this.lastName, this.firstName, this.middleInit);
    }

}
```

Date:

```
public class Date {

    private int month;
    private int day;
    private int year;

    public Date(int theMonth, int theDay, int theYear) {
        setMonth(theMonth);
        setDay(theDay);
        setYear(theYear);
    }


    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }


    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }


    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }


    public void setMonth(int month) {
        if ((month > 0) && (month < 13)) {
            this.month = month;
        } else {
            invalidDate();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param day the day to set
     */
    public void setDay(int day) {
        int[] days = {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

        if (month == 2 && day == 29 && (year % 400 == 0
                || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0))) {
            //day is valid
            this.day = day;
        } else if (day < 1 || day > days[month]) {
            // day is not valid default to 1
            day = 1;
            this.day = day;
        } else {
            //day is valid
            this.day = day;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param year the year to set
     */
    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public void invalidDate() {
        System.out.println("Please input a date number from 1 to 12");

    }


    public String displayFormattedDate() {
        return String.format("%s/%s/%s", String.valueOf(year), String.valueOf(month), String.valueOf(day));
    }
}
```

Personprgraom(main)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PersonProgram {

    Scanner input;
    Person[] people;

    public PersonProgram() {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public void getData() {
        people = new Person[5];
        people[0] = new Person("Smith", "John", 'T', new Date(4, 2, 1992));
        people[1] = new Person("Terry", "TwoToots", 'G', new Date(9, 14, 1990));
        people[2] = new Person("MIke", "Mellow", 'M', new Date(3, 10, 1985));
        people[3] = new Person("Steve", "Ramadam", 'N', new Date(4, 20, 1905));
        people[4] = new Person("Bizkit", "Limp", 'H', new Date(12, 25, 1972));

    }

    public int showMenu() {
        System.out.println("1. Display all names.");
        System.out.println("2. Display info for person by number");
        System.out.println("3. Edit information for person by number");
        System.out.println("4. Exit");
        System.out.println("Choice: ");

        int selection = input.nextInt();
        return selection;
    }

    public void executeChoices(int choice) {
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                menuOption1();
                break;
            case 2:
                menuOption2();
                break;
            case 3:
                menuOption3();
                break;
            case 4:
            //menuOption4();
        }
    }

    public void menuOption1() {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < people.length; counter++) {
            System.out.println(counter + 1 + ". " + people[counter].getFullName());
        }

    }

    public void menuOption2() {
        System.out.println("Enter person number: ");
        int selection = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Full Name: " + people[selection].getFullName());
        System.out.println("Birth Date: " + people[selection].getBirthDate());
    }

    public void menuOption3() {
        System.out.println("Please select a person to edit");

        for (int counter = 0; counter < people.length; counter++) {
            System.out.println(counter + 1 + ". " + people[counter].getFullName());
        }
        int choice;
        choice = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("What would you like to edit?");
        System.out.println("1. First Name");
        System.out.println("2. Last Name");
        System.out.println("3. Middle initial");
        System.out.println("4. Birth Date");
        System.out.println("5. Cancel");

        int menuselect = input.nextInt();

        if (menuselect == 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter the new first name: ");
            people[choice - 1].setFirstName(input.next());
        }

        if (menuselect == 2) {
            System.out.println("Enter the new last name: ");
            people[choice - 1].setLastName(input.next());
        }

        if (menuselect == 3) {
            System.out.println("Enter the new Middle Initial: ");
            people[choice - 1].setMiddleInit(input.next().charAt(0));
        }

        if (menuselect == 4) {
            System.out.println("Enter the new birth date: ");
            System.out.println("Please enter new Year: ");
            int year = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter new month");
            int month = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter new day");
            int day = input.nextInt();
            Date birthDate = new Date(month, day, year);
            people[choice - 1].setBirthDate(birthDate);


        }

        if (menuselect == 5) {
            System.out.println("Please select a person to edit");

            for (int counter = 0; counter < people.length; counter++) {
                System.out.println(counter + 1 + ". " + people[counter].getFullName());
            }
        }
    }

    public void menuOption4() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PersonProgram p = new PersonProgram();
        p.getData();
        int userinput = p.showMenu();
        p.executeChoices(userinput);

    }

}
```

Comment: can i see your classes code?

Comment: what are all the objects that are contained inside your Person class? I am going to guess that's Data class object is called BirthDate and thats why you are returning BirthDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would want another method in the Person class called toString() that does the following

```
public String toString()
{
    return (getFullName() + " DOB: " + birthDate.displayFormattedDate());
}
```

Which would return a string based on your example to be

```
"Smith, John T. DOB: 4/2/1992"
```

Comment: I actually did have a toString in the main before that I couldnt get to work, it would just show a memory location(im guessing, it was a few hex characters). Ill try to put it in People though.

Comment: since you create the method inside the Person class you wouldn't need getters to retrieve it's own instance variables @Konovoloff

Comment: I get "cannot find symbol" error, displayFormattedDate is in the Date class, so do I need to call it some other way?

Comment: Actually nvm, I had a syntax error somewhere. Thank you, this worked.

Answer (score 0):

the whole purpose of *getters* is that they return a property of the object *without any change*. Therefore a getter (usually) does not create new instances of any class. (I write 'usually' because like any other method getters can be implemented to do so but they should not...)

The getter for your `birthDate` property returns the object that has been passed in to the object via constructor (in your example `new Date(4, 2, 1992)`).

And yes, for display you have to apply an appropriate format to it most likely by using the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class from the system lib.